# Java NullPointerException / Type Generics Question

Tags: java, list, generics, nullpointerexception, immutability

I have created a Linked List class from scratch in Java. The goal is for this Linked List class to be **immutable**. I am using generic types (suspected part of issue). The class has three attributes:

```
boolean isEmpty;
T data;
LinkedListClass<T> next;
```

There are also two constructors for creating this class, one is private and the other public:

```
private LinkedListClass(boolean isEmpty, T data, LinkedListClass<T> next){

    this.isEmpty = isEmpty;
    this.data = data;
    this.next = next;

}
```

...

```
public LinkedListClass(){

        LinkedListClass<T> newList = new LinkedListClass<T>(true, null, null);

    }
```

The reason for this is so the user does not have direct access to the variables **isEmpty**, **data** and **next**. So when the user creates a Linked List, the aforementioned variables are assigned to **true**, **null** and **null** respectively by default. N.b. Any method that appends or changes the list in such a way that it is not empty anymore, will hence change the **isEmpty** value to **false**.

I have made a **copyList()** function:

```
 public LinkedListClass<T> copyList() {

    LinkedListClass<T> clonedList = new LinkedListClass<T>();

    if(this.isEmpty) {

        return clonedList;
    }

    clonedList = new LinkedListClass<T>(false, this.data, this.next.copyList() ); //this is line 32


    return clonedList;


}
```

In the **main** method I am simply calling the copy function like so:

```
public class prog7 {

public static void main (String args[]) {

    LinkedListClass<Integer> list1 = new LinkedListClass();
    LinkedListClass<Integer> list2 = new LinkedListClass();
    list2 = list1.copyList();                                 //this is line 7

}
```

}

Upon compiling, the following error occurs:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at LinkedListClass.copyList(LinkedListClass.java:32)
at prog7.main(prog7.java:7)
```

I think the NullPointerException is thrown because when creating a `LinkedListClass<T>`, two of its values are *null*. So when trying to change them or reference them, the exception is thrown. One workaround I have considered is replacing *null* in the public `LinkedListClass<T>` constructor with the *int* value 0. However my IDE complains that the expected type is *T*, but I am providing it with an *int*. So I think this may be a question regarding type generics.

Comment: What semantics has `isEmpty`? Does it mean that `data` is 'empty' (null?), or that the linked list does not have any more nodes? Why does _every_ element in the linked list have an `isEmpty` flag?

Comment: I know that this has probably nothing to do with your question. The problem is imho that your implementation is somehow akward, and I don't see much use in fixing just the specific null-pointer problem while all other things remain untouched.

Comment: The only possible cause of a NullPointerException in the code you have shown us is that `this.next` is null when `copyList` is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem with your public constructor. It should look like that:

```
public LinkedListClass() {
     this(true, null, null);
}
```

In this line

```
LinkedListClass<T> newList = new LinkedListClass<T>(true, null, null);
```

you *don't set parameters at all*, you create a new variable which is not used afterwards.  So `isEmpty` has a default value (`false`).  Read more about constructor overloading.